# remove specific id from array of checked items

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have a list/array of sports which by default all of them are with `checked = true`, in the function below you can see this line `intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);` where `sportIds` is the full list of sports ids and `sportChecked.sport` are the sports with `checked = false` which are the sports that the user unchecked.

Remember: All the sports are `checked = true` by default.

This is an array of 30 items, every item has an unique `id`, as I mentioned all the sports are `checked = true`, but I need the `id: 10` to be `checked = false` by default.

Behind all this code you see, there is already a construction to save in a DB the items that the user `checked = false`, that's why you see here this line `sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);`.

So, in order to do what I want, MY GUESS: I need to put the `id: 10` with `checked=false` in the `var = intersectedSports` which I mentioned above, unless you have a better suggestion for me... so, what do you recommend my friends ?

```
  var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
      intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);
  if (sports.length) {
    sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
      sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
      return sport;
    });
  }
```

**Just in case: I am using Lodash and Angular**

Comment: Assuming the sport with id of 10 is always in the sports array, `_.findWhere(sports, {id: 10}).checked = false`.

Comment: @mathewbergt where should I put that ? I did already and is not working, the ```id: 10``` is still ```checked = true```

Comment: Without knowing what your code looks like I can't be of too much more help. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZPPOFnwQmcwqmCcLuE6?p=preview) is a really basic example where I setup a sports array and the call the _.findWhere function to set the sport with id: 10 to checked=false.

Comment: @mathewbergt post it as an answer so I can give you the best answer check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the logic into something like this:

```
     // build a list of the sports that should be unchecked
     var unchecked = sportChecked.sport.concat(10);

     // add a checked property to each sport
     _.each(sports, function(sport){
        sport.checked = !_.contains(unchecked, sport.id);
     });
```